# What is the most recommended way to using timer in Java

Tags: java, timer, executors

I am working on socket programming in java.I must use timer in each connection and I am using timer like following code:

```
this.timeoutTask = new TimeoutTask();
this.timeoutTimer = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private void startTimer(ConnectionState state) {
    int period;
    connectionState = state;
    period = connectionState.getTimeoutValue();
    future = timeoutTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeoutTask, period, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
 private void stopTimer() {

    if (timeoutTimer != null) {
        future.cancel(true);
    }

}

private void shutdownTimer() {

    timeoutTimer.shutdown();
    timeoutTask.cancel();
}
```

I am using 'stopTimer' function for suspending timer and 'shutdownTimer' function for deleting timer task.
But when use timer like this,sometimes,running a thousands of timer thread because thousand of time is alive simultanously.
What is the best way prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating thread for every task, you should use thread pool:

```
this.timeoutTask = new TimeoutTask();
static ScheduledExecutorService timeoutTimer = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);


private void startTimer(ConnectionState state) {
    int period;
    connectionState = state;
    period = connectionState.getTimeoutValue();
    future = timeoutTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeoutTask, period, period, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}

private void stopTimer() {
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

Now task will executing in free thread from thread pool.

And you don't need stoping `ExecutorService`, just cancel task with `future.cancel(true);`